# A "registry explorer" that works like Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-registry, sysadmin

I'm looking for a **free** **portable** program to browse and modify registry values with **perfect ease**. It must have the basic features that `regedit` already have (e.g. import, export, etc) plus these features:

1. Smart (filterable) **wildcard** search on keys **and values**.
2. Clickable omnibar to navigate directly to any of the parent keys with a single click (just like what we have in Windows Explorer):

   [image]
3. Omnibar must be text-**edit**able (just like what we have in Windows Explorer):

   [image]
4. Keyboard shortcuts that are identical to Windows Explorer (e.g. <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename a key, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to create a key, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> to navigate backwards, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to navigate forwards, etc).

Currently I'm using [Registry Commander](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=408), which only supports the first point.

Comment: [Multi Commander](http://multicommander.com/) has first three features (not in entirety).

Comment: @Firelord, The search doesn't seem to be working. (That's a serious showstopper.) Registry Commander is able to search the entire tree for specific key and values, is Multi Commander able to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Altap Salamander](http://www.altap.cz/). The Registry features are described [here](http://www.altap.cz/salamander/features/registry-editor-search-registry/).

[image: Registry Editor]

The only requirement where it fails it that it's not delivered as a portable applications. But if you have a look at the forum, you'll notice that there have been successful efforts to make it portable.

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be some problem with the search. For example, if you'd install and then uninstall [clover](http://ejie.me/), and then search for "Clover" using Registry Commander, the entries come up within a few seconds. But using Altap Salamander, they don't appear. Also, after the 30 days trial, does the program become fully "locked"?

Comment: It doesn't stop working after the trial, but it does present you with the same registration dialog and you have to wait a while until you can dismiss it. I can't comment on the search results issue you encountered, as I don't have a Windows installation right now to test this on.

Comment: Also I've been noticing weird [access is denied](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2YOcW.png) issues when searching, even while running the program as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

[RegistryFS (Github)](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet/tree/master/sample/RegistryFS) can mount the Windows registry on a Windows drive, so for instance it creates a `R:\` drive in which you see the keys hierarchy.

Being a Windows drive, you can browse it with Windows Explorer, and thus benefit from all Windows Explorer features.

It is meant as a demonstration for the open source library [Dokan.net](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet), so you will have to compile it by yourself, unfortunately.